# How to explicitly set the tabname of a new gnome-terminal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, quoting, gnome-terminal

I want to explicity rename a tab in gnome-terminal on startup of the tab. I don't want to use gnome-terminal --title flag as that gets reset by my systems bashrc file after whatever else is supposed to run.

I have used  this command with success in a normal terminal

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne '\033]0;TABNAME\007'"
```

This command works fine to rename the current tab's name, but when I try to use it in conjunction with gnome-terminal execute command, I am not getting proper output.

I have used gnome-terminal --e flag to execute simple commands with success, something like this will bring up a new terminal and echo hey then return to bash

`gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'echo hey';bash"`

Here is what I am trying ***note the escaped " " marks that I added***

```
TABNAME="export PROMPT_COMMAND=\"echo -ne '\033]0;TABNAME\007'\""
gnome-terminal --tab --e "bash -c $TABNAME;bash"
```

I always get weird output no matter how I change the quotes, but I think that is where the problem is.